# Vue component recycling causing watch to fire unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a reusable checkbox component for vue and I've run into an interesting issue caused by vue's recycling of unused components.

This is best seen with an example:

```js
Vue.component("checkbox", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot></slot>:
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" v-on:change="updateVModel"/>
      <span>changed!</span>  
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {checked: this.value};
  },
  watch: {
    value(val){
      this.changeAnimation();
      this.checked = val;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeAnimation(){
      let $span = this.$el.querySelector("span");
      $span.classList.remove("animate");
      setTimeout(() => $span.classList.add("animate"), 50);
    },
    updateVModel(){
      this.changeAnimation();//this line is redundant since watch.value runs anyway
      this.$emit("input", this.checked);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#menu",
  data: {
    menu: 0,
    checked0: true,
    checked1: false
  }
});
```

```css
span{
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
span.animate{
  animation: notice-me .3s ease-in-out 4 alternate
}


@keyframes notice-me{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div v-if="menu == 0">
    <button v-on:click="menu = 1">Go to menu 1</button>
    <h3>Menu 0</h3>
    <checkbox v-model="checked0">checked0</checkbox>
    <checkbox v-model="checked0">checked0</checkbox>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <button v-on:click="menu = 0">Go to menu 0</button>
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <checkbox v-model="checked1">checked1</checkbox>
    <checkbox v-model="checked1">checked1</checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made my components as so whenever the value changes, either from a user click(with `v-on:click`) or from the variable itself changing (with `watch.value`), the word "changed!" blinks besides the checkbox a couple of times.  Everything works fine, but the problem arises when we change menus using the "Change to menu" button and checked0 and checked1 are different values.  "changed" will blink even though it shouldn't have.

This is obviously caused by vue recycling the components and using them for another variable.  Since the variable's value is different from the old one, `watch.value` is run, triggering the animation when we'd expect it not to happen.

I did a little bit of research and found that I could give all my different checkboxes [vue keys](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) like so: `<checkbox v-model="checked1" key="thing1">checked1</checkbox>`, but I want to fix this elegantly and allow vue to recycle whatever it wants.  There should be a way to detect if the value changed because it actually did or because of recycling.

So my question is how to I fix this problem, or how do I write my code differently to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) should really be associated with the conditionally-rendered (by `v-for` or `v-if`) unit. It should be bound to whatever is unique about the unit. In your case, you can use `menu`:

```
  <div v-if="menu == 0" :key="menu">
    <button v-on:click="menu = 1">Go to menu 1</button>
    <h3>Menu 0</h3>
    <checkbox v-model="checked0">checked0</checkbox>
    <checkbox v-model="checked0">checked0</checkbox>
  </div>
  <div v-else :key="menu">
    <button v-on:click="menu = 0">Go to menu 0</button>
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <checkbox v-model="checked1">checked1</checkbox>
    <checkbox v-model="checked1">checked1</checkbox>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy.  As I said (in paragraph 4) I'm aware that I can use vue keys, however I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way to fix this than giving all my components random ids.

Comment: The fact that you have the repeated structure there suggests that you should be using an array. I think that's the more elegant approach, but you will still need to use `key`s. It will just be a more conventional use of them.

Comment: I have a complex multi-page web application with hundreds of checkboxes.  On that scale I don't think it would be an elegant solution.  Would you know of another way for me to do this or have those components generate their own random keys?

Comment: Oooooh. That's a thing you could do. That is a very elegant solution.  Thanks.